# How to get form data to the next page

Tags: php

I am trying to check the form on this page and if everything is entered correct I want send the `$name`, `$sport`, `$beoefenaar` and `$text` to the page `http://localhost/051R4-verwerk.php`. But the variables aren't being sent to that page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<title>Inzendopdracht 051R4</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>  
<a href='viewguestbook.php'>View Guestbook</a>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $sportErr = $beoefenaarErr = $textErr = "";
$name = $sport = $beoefenaar = $text ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$valid = true;

if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
$valid = false;
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["sport"])) {
$sportErr = "Sport is required";
$valid = false;
} else {
$sport = test_input($_POST["sport"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["text"])) {
$textErr = "Comment is required";
$valid = false;
} else {
$text = test_input($_POST["text"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["beoefenaar"])) {
$beoefenaarErr = "Comment is required";
} else {
$beoefenaar = test_input($_POST["beoefenaar"]);
}

if($valid){
 header("location: http://localhost/051R4-verwerk.php"); 
}  

}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Laat hier u bericht achter</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Sport: <select name="sport">
            <option valeu="">
            <option valeu="Tennis">Tennis
            <option valeu="Voetbal">Voetbal
            <option valeu="Running">Running
            <option valeu="Tafeltenis">Tafeltenis
            <option valeu="Squash">Squash
            <option valeu="Wielrennen">Wielrennen
            <option valeu="Boksen">Boksen
        </select>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $sportErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Beoefenaar:
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="beoefenaar" value="0" checked>Nee
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="beoefenaar" value="1">Ja
<br><br>
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Schrijf hier u bericht*"  /></textarea>
<span class="error"> <?php echo $textErr;?></span>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Verstuur"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what "next" page? You only have the one file here and using "self" as the action. What's in the `051R4-verwerk.php` file?

Comment: You should also be getting undefined variables notices.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you aren't including your second PHP file.  You are redirecting to the second PHP file.  This means that your are instructing the browser to load up a new page with a new HTTP request.  PHP can't store variables between calls, so when this new request comes in all previous variables (and history) are lost.  Each page executes completely separate from every other page.

Instead, the simplest way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish is with sessions.  This allows you to store information on a user between script executions.  PHP will automatically create cookies for you and manage the session information.  You just have to get your data into the session, and then get it back out of the session in your second script.  In your first script that could look something like this:

```
if($valid){
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['sport'] = $sport;
    /// and more
    header("location: http://localhost/051R4-verwerk.php"); 
}
```

Then in your receiving script:

```
$name = isset( $_SESSION['name'] ) ? $_SESSION['name'] : '';
$sport = isset( $_SESSION['sport'] ) ? $_SESSION['sport'] : '';
```

This will only work if the two scripts are hosted by the same server and on the same domain.  There are lots of tutorials out there about using sessions.  You will actually still have to validate the data again in your second script, because a user can go directly to it without any information in the session.

Your second option would be to include the second script instead of redirecting to it, in which case your variables will actually be available, but you will also have to adjust the way your first page works.  Maybe something like:

```
if($valid){
    include "051R4-verwerk.php";
    exit;
}
```